# How do I write a native method?

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

Now I got a .so file and a C++ header file.
There is a function as follows:

```
BOOL __stdcall HK_STD_CreateHandle(IN PBYTE pFileHdrBuffer, IN DWORD dwFileHdrSize, IN DWORD dwBufferSize, OUT HANDLE&  hHandle);
typedef BYTE *        PBYTE;
typedef unsigned long DWORD;
typedef void *  HANDLE;
```

I think I can implement a Java class to use the .so file:

```
public class Decoder {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("SingleDecode");
    }

    public native boolean HK_STD_CreateHandle(
        byte[] pFileHdrBuffer,
        int dwFileHdrSize,
        int dwBufferSize,
        int hHandle);
}
```

But I don't know how to write the native function. Can anybody help me?

Comment: what you are trying to do ?did u get the .so file from your JNI file

Comment: Thanks, I want to use a third-party .so file. I thought I could use it directly(just declare a native method in Java), but I now know I must implement a new .so file with ndk to use the third-party .so file.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your native function must have a certain name. For example, if you have a class MyActivity in the package com.android.test where you have declared the native method, the corresponding native function must be named:

```
Java_com_android_test_MyActivity_functionName();
```

Next, the native function must receive two additional arguments that are not explicitly defind by you (they're sent by the Java environment). I could explain it here, but it's probably easiest if you read up on JNI. Try Wikipedia for example:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface

There are also a few samples that comes with the NDK that will help you out.